# Android - Text positioning

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a very, very, very simple application that I'm working on (been trying my luck at writing an app in Java instead of Unity) and I have a background image that is fullscreen, this image has a lot of design and scales well with every device, and looks great (tested on every resolution we can think of).

However the text doesn't want to stay where it belongs, and that's not permissible. We have a basic setup, similar to this (however with about 6 hours of design work put into it):

[image]

and we need text to be centered in the squares at all times. How can we do this? Do we have to manually position and size it for each resolution? That seems like hell.

Comment: What kind of layout are you using? Linear,  relative..?

Comment: @j_vega19 -- Relative currently, but it can be changed with ease. Our entire design is just one image that needs text drawn over it.

Comment: So the four squares are the background image?

Answer (score 0):

With a [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), if I understand correctly, the boxes will be parents and the text that goes into the boxes will be the children. You can put your TextViews into the boxes and then use things like `android:layout_centerVertical` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal` in order to make sure they are centered. Make sure to use `sp` for your font size so that it scales correctly with the density of the display.

Comment: There is only a single image which is the background, there is not a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Then the screen is the parent and the `TextView`s you put inside are the children. Perhaps I misunderstood the problem, but it looks like you have four boxes and the text is going into the boxes. I assumed that the boxes would be children of the screen and the `TextView`s in the boxes to be children of the boxes. Regardless, you can make sure the text is centered with `android:layout_centerVertical` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal` in the layout XML.