# Changing the height of a TextView yields no results

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm having trouble with getting my TextViews to move. I'm trying to create a simple system that allows me to place text based on screen % of pixels, using a relative layout. The following is the code I have. (Please note, I must support API 11).

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

System.err.println("MWidth: " + width + " MHeight: " + height);

int rowOneHeight = (int)Math.floor((float)height * 0.65);
System.err.println("New height: " + rowOneHeight);

days.setHeight(rowOneHeight);
hours.setHeight(rowOneHeight);
```

This yields results:

```
29735-29735/ct.test.testingW/System.err﹕ MWidth: 1080 MHeight: 1776
04-29 20:09:39.401  29735-29735/ct.test.testing W/System.err﹕ New height: 1154
```

However the textviews are at the vew top of the screen? I don't understand why.

Comment: You want the `TextView` to move, but you set its `height`? Why should setting the `height` will make it move? Try this: set the `backgroundColor` of the `TextView` to `red` and confirm if the `height` of the `TextView` is updated.

Comment: Show your layout, I think it could be possible to solve your problem via xml, keeping code clean.

Comment: Is [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957086/android-text-positioning) you had asked a hour before this one concerns the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use     LinearLayout and set the weights.  Then you can define size based on percent of the screen

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:layout_weight="3">
    <View
        ...
        android:weight="1"/>
    <View
        ...
        android:weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The top view would consume 33.33% of the screen and the bottom would consume the other 66.66%.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [setY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setY(float)) instead of setHeight of textview.

Changing height of textview will not change "position" where the text is displayed on screen if you didn't set Gravity to a non default value (= Top-Left). By changing height/width of a view only bottom and right side will be "moved" (anchor is on top left corner of a view).

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

System.err.println("MWidth: " + width + " MHeight: " + height);

int rowOneHeight = (int)Math.floor((float)height * 0.65);
System.err.println("New height: " + rowOneHeight);

// Set distance to top (in pxl)
days.setY(rowOneHeight);
hours.setY(rowOneHeight);
```